# Read/Write ProcessMemory Declaration

Tags: c#, windows

I am trying to make a memory scanner, for that I need to call read and write proccessmemory,
I searched in google and find out the declaration is :

```
 [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")] 
 public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(ntPtr hProcess, 
                         IntPtr lpBaseAddress, byte[] lpBuffer, 
                         UInt32 nSize, ref UInt32 lpNumberOfBytesRead);
```

I am trying to put it in main function, out of main.

But I always get a compiler error.

where should I place it to get the `ReadProcesssMemory`?

after the guy helped me (the post under me) i get this error:

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'DllImportAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What compiler error? Linenumbers and details please.

Comment: @user1124295, make sure you have added the `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace to the `using` section of your file.

Answer (score 4):

You have an error in your declaration. There is no such type as `ntPtr` (first argument of your function). You probably want wanted to use the [`IntPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx) type:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(
        IntPtr hProcess,
        IntPtr lpBaseAddress,
        byte[] lpBuffer,
        UInt32 nSize,
        ref UInt32 lpNumberOfBytesRead
    );

    public static void Main()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: The typo of doom strikes again!

Comment: @Oded, it's not the typo that strikes me so much here. We all do typos. It's the unwillingness of people to read error messages. Especially in a compiled and strongly typed language.

Comment: Well, it is easier to get someone on StackOverflow to point out your typo for you...

Comment: That's what strikes me. The typo is already pointed out to you by the compiler and despite this you post on StackOverflow. Anyway.